# Power Snare Is a 14.5 LB weight enough to kill a racoon?

Tags: trapping

I have a home made snare that when tightened, causes a weight of 14.5LB to fall, pulling the snare loop closed and towards a chain link bolted to the ground so that the animal will be pushed against that point and the weight will hopefully choke it quickly.

My question is, is 14.5LB enough weight to keep the animal down? It's a fairly big raccoon, and the ground is dirt which it might dig into. I am wondering if it could lift some of the weight with its paws.

Additional Information:

- The weight falls about a yard. Its enough to where the snare closes and is brought to the point and there is still more room after its pulled against the point.
- I know it will close around the racoon's neck because I set it 3 inches above the ground and about 6 - 8in diameter. Also, racoons always walk with their head in front of their paws.
- Pets are not an issue where I live.
- The way I set the trap, and the location I set it there is no way for a limb to get caught in the trap.

Here is a setup similar to mine except that a bent tree is used to provide the pull and their is not point that the closed snare is pulled against:

[image: snare]

Comment: There is not enough information here.  How far does the weight fall?  How do you know that snare will close around the Raccoons neck?

Comment: Separate from my comment above, how do you keep pets belonging to you or your neighbor from getting caught in the trap? What are you going to do if an animal (raccoon or pet) gets a limb caught in the trap and is alive when you find it?

Comment: @JamesJenkins Good point. See updated question

Comment: Not sure where you live, but I know that in some areas trapping with a snare requires a special trapping license.